# Example of OOP concepts in Android

Tags: android, inheritance, polymorphism, encapsulation

Hi I am just wondering what if any is the difference with the OOP concepts when using them in developing desktop apps using JAVA and then implementing them in Android apps?

I am just curious to know if there is any major difference when putting these concepts into my android code before I go and do it.

Thanks

Comment: OOP is OOP is OOP.  The core concepts don't change just because the platform does.  The only real difference is what classes you have available.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference at all in coding style, but since you are coding for a mobile device which tends to have low memory, small screen etc, you have to take special care while allocating memory and other resources....

For a definitive guide, do's and dont's refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html).

Answer (score 0):

No difference. Android uses Java as programming language and OOP is not programming language dependent.

Answer (score 0):

NO difference on the basic ground , as you are using core java which is same for both , the way you code the OOP is also the same , but new are the classes you have to deal with the android which are different according to the need. For example : dealing with the activities ,are new which does not exist in case of simple java programming.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is there no difference, but you can, and should, reuse exactly the same OO code between your Android and desktop/server side applications.